# Make 'All Items' my default location in Google Docs

Tags: google, google-drive

I'd like to make 'All Items' my default location when I load up Google Docs instead of 'Home'. Clicking to remove the 'Home' label or having to navigate to 'All Items' every single time I want to search all items is getting somewhat annoying. Also, I'd rather not bookmark Google Docs since I'll be on shared machines at school. Is there a setting for what I want?

Answer (score 1):

There is no setting for what you want, but you can do it by opening https://docs.google.com/?authuser=0#all instead of docs.google.com

The best thing would be to Create a Bookmark for https://drive.google.com/?authuser=0#all and open it whenever you want to open Google Docs.